# Serverless framework python packaging with custom modules

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a serverless function

serverless.yml

```
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: ap-southeast-2
  
functions:
  populateData:
    handler: handler.populate
    timeout: 900
    package:
      include:
        - lib/**

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true
    #Get rid of unnecessary package files
    slim: true
    #But keep necessary binary files to avoid "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned"
    strip: false

package:
  individually: true
```

My lib/ contains three files xyz.py xyz1.py xyz2.py

Inside those files, I am importing packages

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datasource as ds
import numpy as np
import traceback
import properties as pt
```

Inside my handler.py I am importing my files like below

```
from lib import xyz as pd
from lib import xyz1 as md
from lib import xyz2
```

it gets deployed successfully but when I invoke the function I am getting the following error

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': cannot import name 'pandas' from 'lib' (/var/task/lib/__init__.py)",
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "stackTrace": []
}
```

Not sure what I am missing here.Any help/ pointers would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Worked after reducing the imported libraries and adding layers to the the function

```
functions:
  data:
    handler: handler.data
    timeout: 900
    package:
      include:
        - lib/**
    layers:
      - { Ref: PythonRequirementsLambdaLayer }
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true
    #Get rid of unnecessary package files
    slim: true
    #But keep necessary binary files to avoid "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned"
    strip: false
    layer: true
```